# NUnit TestFixtureAttribute: How do I pass a DateTime instance into the test class constructor via the TestFixtureAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I started using the TestFixtureAttribute to execute a unit test multiple times with different input values. The method I am testing is similar to a TryParse operation where method returns a bool result and sets an output parameter to the parsed value. In success cases I expect the method to return true. However I also want to verify the value in the output parameter. The output parameter is of type DateTime. How can I pass an instance of DateTime via the TestFixtureAttribute.

```
[TestFixture("121231225959", true, new DateTime(2012,12,31,22,59,59)]
```

The above gives an compile error as it expects a const value to be passed in the attribute.

Any ideas would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this cannot be done using attributes because only compile-time constants can pass as attribute parameters.

What you can do is create a loop inside your test and pass the values there. For example:

```
DateTime[] dates = new [] { ... };
foreach (DateTime dt in dates)
{
    // Test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think attribute pair [Datapoints]/[Theory] can resolve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in as a string and create the DateTime in the constructor.